# C# Streaming to HTML5 audio element

Tags: c#, html, audio, stream

I'm doing text-to-speech via a webpage UI.

The workflow is

1. The user types some text into a TextBox
2. User clicks a "Speak" button
3. The server sends the text to the Azure CognitiveServices TextToSpeech service
4. Azure sends back a byte array, containing an MP3
5. The server sends a copy of the byte array to an HTML5 <audio> element on the webpage *
6. The <audio> element plays the speech on the browser machine.
7. The user can then click an 'OK' button for the server to save the byte array, or go back to step 1 to change the text and try again

I have it all working. However, at step 5, I resorted to writing the bytes to a file in a web-visible directory, then setting the <audio> element's source property to the URL of that file. That feels like a workaround rather than a good solution.

Is there a better way to pass the byte array or a MemoryStream directly to the <audio> element without writing and reading a file? Or some other mechanism to play the speech data on the browser machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar working using an external API as the byte source instead of CognitiveServices.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AudioController : Controller
{
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Audio()
{
    var httpClient = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<HttpClient>();
    var obj = JsonUtils.DeserializeObject<ApiPayload>(payload);

    string endpoint = "/some-api/audiofile";
    var builder = new UriBuilder(endpoint);

    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(builder.Uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    if (stream != null)
    {
        string fileName = "your-file.mp3";
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "audio/mpeg")
        {
            FileDownloadName = fileName
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound("No stream found for given payload.");
    }
}
}
```

Then in html call the endpoint:

```
<div>
     <audio autoplay controls>
          <source src="/api/audio" type="audio/mpeg">
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
     </audio>
</div>
```

Make sure your MIME type is included as that stumped me for a bit at the start ("audio/mpeg" should be fine for your use as well).
The fileName will be what is the default name if the user chooses to save the file.

A little late but hope this helps